# A team has 35 players. Advice needed for different combinations of players.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The team has $2$ players suitable for position $1$. $11$ players suitable for position $2$. $12$ suitable for position $3$ and $10$ suitable for position $4$. For every game there must be $11$ players consisting from the team and $1$ and **only** $1$ of position $1$ is allowed.

a) How many ways can there be exactly $3$ players in position $2$? (independently from the rest of the team)

b) How many ways are there to create a team consisting of $4$ players in position $2$, $4$ players in position $3$, and $2$ players in position $4$? (There should also be one player of position $1$ chosen.)

c) $1$ player for position $1$ has already been chosen. How many ways can the rest of the team be formed with no other restrictions than the other player for position $1$ not being able to be chosen?

d) Position $1$ has already been decided. How many ways can $2$ players of position $4$ be chosen and any combination of $8$ players from positions $2$ and $3$ be chosen with this fixed choice of position $1$?

For c I had thought the answer would be $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ Where $n = 11$ and $k = 10$? But wanted to check as not sure.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No, the players are distinct and we just want to count ways to select the individuals, when not concerned about order or positions (beside only allowing the 1 player of position 1).

Answer (score 1):

> > The team has $2$ players suitable for position $1$. $11$ players suitable for position $2$. $12$ suitable for position $3$ and $10$ suitable for position $4$. For every game there must be $11$ players consisting from the team and $1$ and **only** $1$ of position $1$ is allowed.
> >
> > c) $1$ player for position $1$ has already been chosen. How many ways can the rest of the team be formed with no other restrictions than the other player for position $1$ not being able to be chosen?
>
> For c I had thought the answer would be $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ Where $n = 11$ and $k = 10$? But wanted to check as not sure.

You are not concerned about order of selection, so you are counting combinations, not permutations.   Also, the numbers are off.

You want to count combinations (selections) of $11-1$ players from $11+12+10$ players available from positions $2,3,4$.   So the count is $^{33}\mathrm C_{10}$. $$\dfrac{33!}{10!~23!}$$